# How do I add my existing audio notes to the Google Recorder app on my Pixel 7 Pro?

Tags: audio, google-pixel, device-migration

I used audio notes extensively on my old Samsung phone. Now I'm migrating to a Pixel 7 pro and I love the [Google Recorder app](https://recorder.withgoogle.com/) which is only available on Pixel phones. It has live transcription and audio search. However, I can't seem to find a way to import my old audio notes into the recorder app. I have the audio files on my new phone as well as on Google drive, but there doesn't seem to be an option to add audio files. I'd like to keep all my audio notes in one app so I can search them, and of course getting the free auto-transcription for my old notes is a major bonus.

Is there any solution to this? At an extreme I could re-record the audio notes by playing them into a high quality microphone plugged into my phone. But that would be very time consuming so if there is any way to directly add the files please advise!

Comment: I have been searching for an answer on this, and it seems as if it's impossible. Which is a huge oversight

Comment: Also looking for this, so annoying. I've got a recording I want to put over and I may just play it on some speakers while my pixel records it again